# Why do the characters of Fire Force always say "Látom"?

Tags: fire-force

In Fire Force there are some religious characters like a nun which is part of company 8, and her and other characters when are saying preaching-like sentences many times end the phrase with the word "Látom". What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained near the start of the series, in the world of Fire Force there is a very close connection between the special firefighting forces and the church, and in some sense dealing with the Infernals is considered a sacred duty (since the Infernals are considered to be in pain, and killing them allows them to be at peace).

The full prayer that is said when they defeat an Infernal is based on one from the real-world Anglican text "[The Book of Common Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Common_Prayer)" that is commonly used in funerals:

> Forasmuch as it hath pleased Almighty God of his great mercy to take unto himself the
>   soul of our dear brother here departed, we therefore commit his body to the ground; **earth
>   to earth, ashes to ashes, dust to dust**; in sure and certain hope of the Resurrection to eternal life, through our Lord Jesus Christ; who shall change our vile body, that it may be like unto his glorious body, according to the mighty working, whereby he is able to subdue all things to himself.

Very roughly, "people were made out of earth by God and then they get returned to the ground until the end times".

Of course, in Fire Force much of the Church's doctrine centres around fire, light and the Sun, and so they focus mainly on the "ashes to ashes" part.

So, to bring it all back to the original question, "látom" is being used in the same way that a Christian would say "amen", to mark the end of the prayer. "Amen" roughly translates as "So be it", while "látom" is apparently Hungarian for "I see it". It may have been chosen just because it sounds good (it has a similar cadence to "amen"), but I have also seen some people online suggest that it could be short for saying "I see your light" which would definitely link back to the key doctrines of the Church.